# Hide querystring in url using MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, query-string, querystringparameter

Hi i have this application that needs a user to login.
Once the user is logged in, he is redirected to a page displaying documents for that user.

To display that information, I call the correct action on the controller and i pass my user-object. This object contains username and password.
When i look at my url it looks like :

```
http://localhost:53703/Documents?UserName=bart&UserId=10&Password=AllPhi%242015
```

Is there a way that I can hide those querystring-values (UserName=bart&UserId=10&Password=AllPhi%242015)

Comment: If the user is logged in with any of the built in mechanisms you should access the user through the controllers User-property, there's no need to pass it in.

Comment: @Daniel what do you mean with the controllers User-property?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: What are you using then?

Comment: I am using the ASP.Net membership, but i modified it. And so the "user-object" in my controllers stays NULL. That is the reason why I pass my object to the controller.

Comment: Now in this case I'm passing a user-object, but I guess the same would happen when I pass another kind of object. So my question is more general than this. How can I hide that querystring?

Comment: At the very least you could use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx That way the User-property won't be null.

Comment: 1) *Don't pass your entire User object in the URL* 2) The query string is part of the URL, so no you can't remove it from the URL. Otherwise, it's not the same URL. 3) Did I mention that you should please for the love of all things good and holy *not* pass your entire User object in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not object strongly enough to sidestepping the built in auth-mechanisms, but to answer the question: You cannot hide the query-string. 
If you want to hide data when you are sending from a client you need to do a post request instead of a get, but the post-data is still visible in the request (in plain text)

But in this case it seems you want to pass data between actions, and then you want to use tempdata. Look here for reference: http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications